# How to start a loop from where the user stop the loop?

Tags: python

How do I make a loop start from where it was left off? For example

```
def nextSquare():
    i=0

    while i<10:
        k = (input("enter number"))
        i=i+1
        if k=='Done':
            break;
        else:
            continue
```

If I stopped the loop at 5 the next time I want it to run from `i = 6` instead of `i = 0`.
Thanks.

Comment: pass the variable `i` to the function and return the current value after breaking out of loop, so that you can pass it again and continue from where you left

Answer (score 0):

In order to store the iteration index, you can pass it as a parameter and return it back to the calling function.

For example:

```
def lol(i):
    while(i < 10):
        print(i) #unique value of i
        k = int(input())

        if k == 5:
            print("Iteration skipped")
            break
        else:
            print("Next iteration")
        i += 1
    return i

i = 0
i = lol(i)
i = lol(i)
i = lol(i)
i = lol(i)
```

In this example, I am calling `lol` four times. It stores the iteration index as `i` when it is called. It passes the same index so that it resumes the iteration from that index. If `k != 5`, then it increments the index, and returns it. Else, the operation is skipped.

**ALSO**

Looking at your example, I would say that there is a logical mistake.

`k = (input("enter number"))`

In this statement, you are asking for a number. However, you are comparing it to `'Done'`. A logical mistake, I would say.

Comment: Thanks Im asking input from the user, how can I assume user will stop at 5 only.

Comment: You are taking `k` as an input. Whenever `k` is equal to 5, the loop terminates. It's not necessary to use `5`. You can also use 0 and 1 to continue the loop, or terminate it.

Comment: Im not getting. How to start and end a loop with user input please thanks